# Configure Apache2 to allow clients to run Perl Scripts in cgi-bin

Tags: perl, apache, url, cgi-bin

I have two perl scripts; one acts like the client (and queries); the other acts like the server and returns information.  On an Apache server (not my own) they work perfectly.

However, on my ubuntu/Linux_box with Apache2 (that I set up) they do not; I get a 404 not found error.  The  cgi-bin directory is located at usr/lib/cgi-bin.  What specific files/settings etc have to be changed/altered/etc.  And,  what specific changes/alterations/etc. need to be made?

**Edit:**
I changed the httpd.conf and tried *both* of the following (but neither worked):

```
ScriptAlias  /diag/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin
ScriptAlias  /diag/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
```

I am using a perl script as the client, and it did not work. For illustration purposes I attempted to locate the file with the browser shown in the 2nd pic.

[image: linux]

[image: ms]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are receiving 404, it means that the file does not even exist in the correct location. In the httpd.conf look for the "ScriptAlias" directive that has an entry for cgi-bin, should be something like

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /some_folder/cgi-bin

Once you know the correct folder, the 404 error should go away.

Two other points -
1. For cgi files, ensure that the execute bit is set.
2. Verify that the location of perl matches the one in the perl script.

Comment: Are there multiple Apache installs on this server ? What is the listen address in this httpd.conf ?